# Add button inside Input field ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, input

I want to add a button inside my `input` in `React`. Now I know I could place it there by setting the button absolute and moving in on there using `css` but I assume that there is a better option to do it?

My moving a field there with absolute value then the search text might go under button.

This is the end result I would like to have but having a normal button there would suffice also.

[image: Searchbox]

Here is my input box code:

[image: Edit mystifying-water-8the6]

In this case I can put 2 boxes under eachother and when I place a button inside `input` I get an error that `input can't have any child elements`.

Comment: There isn't a better way to do it, as you've seen from that error you can't put elements inside an `<input/>` so using CSS to make icon *appear* inside them is your only choice. This is also what all the CSS libraries like Bootstrap and Material UI do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a simple code snippet, how you can achieve what you are asking :

---

```css
.inputWithButton {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width : 200px;
}

.inputWithButton input{
    width: 70%;
    height: 25px;
    padding-right: 60px;
}

.inputWithButton button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top : 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='inputWithButton'>
  <input type="text"/>
  <button>Search</button>
</div>
```

You can also check same change on :

[image: Edit romantic-lewin-q7s7b]

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the text still goes under the button which is something I wanted to avoid but I think I can go on and figure it out from here.

Answer (score 2):

If your intention is to have just a "search button", may I recommend the [Input Group](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/forms/input-group/#button-addons) from [react-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap) lib. You can add a button with whatever you want inside of it. (Using v2.1.0 - Bootstrap 5)

```js
<InputGroup className="mb-3">
  <FormControl placeholder="Search" />
  <Button variant="outline-secondary"></Button>
</InputGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this. When I used the examples, they weren't useful.

```
<input className=' ml-4 rounded-lg bg-inputbg  text-white placeholder-placeholder placeholder-opacity-75 pl-3'
      placeholder='Search'
      value={filterText}
      name="search"
      onChange={handleClick}
/>
<button className='bg-inputbg rounded-lg -m-4 pb-1'><AiOutlineSearch/></button>
```

I used to tailwind CSS library. -m-4 is important for seems.